# Check which BarCheckItem is checked in Group

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

How can i check which barcheckitem is checked in a certain group?

I am dinamicaly creating check items in a BarSubItem. 
There are 2 values i am using to create a certain checkitem: item.naziv_programa and item.tabela.

This is part of code which creates items:

```
For Each item As ReturnList In mysql.vratiPrograme()
        Dim barmanager1 As New BarManager
        Dim BarCheckItem = New BarCheckItem()
        BarCheckItem.Content = item.naziv_programa
        BarCheckItem.Name = item.tabela
        BarCheckItem.GroupIndex = 1
        Program.Items.Add(BarCheckItem)
    Next
```

I need to run another function on buttonclick in which i will need to pass "Name" of the checked checkitem as a string:

```
 Public Function vratiOpcijePrograma(ByVal tabela As String)....
```

Comment: You just want one name of checked? what happens if more than one button is checked?

Comment: @Mederic That's why i have 'BarCheckItem.GroupIndex = 1' so every checkbox acts as a radio button, only one item per group can be checked.

Comment: then did you try: `for each itemer in Program.Items if item.checked = true return item.name end if next`